# Counting the frequency of each word in a given text

Tags: python, string

I am looking for a python program that counts the frequencies of each word in a text, and output each word with its count and line numbers where it appears.
We define a word as a contiguous sequence of non-white-space characters. (hint: `split()`)

Note: different capitalizations of the same character sequence should be considered same word, e.g. Python and python, I and i.

The input will be several lines with the empty line terminating the text. Only alphabet characters and white spaces will be present in the input.

The output is formatted as follows:
Each line begins with a number indicating the frequency of the word, a white space, then the word itself, and a list of line numbers containing this word.

Sample Input

```
Python is a cool language but OCaml
is even cooler since it is purely functional
```

Sample Output

```
3 is 1 2
1 a 1
1 but 1
1 cool 1
1 cooler 2
1 even 2
1 functional 2
1 it 2
1 language 1
1 ocaml 1
1 purely 2
1 python 1
1 since 2
```

PS.
I am not a student I am learning Python on my own..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: a program that counts the frequencies of each word in a text,  and output each word with its count and line numbers where it appears.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through your text. People ask and answer question on this site. What is your question?

Comment: how do i write program using function?

Comment: Have you tried anythin yourself? If so, post your code and explain where you're stuck. People tend to be a lot nicer and provide an aswer if you prove you mmade an effort yourself. HINT: check `with`-statement and the `collections`-module.

Comment: What are we supposed to with the *hint: `split()*? How did you come across this *problem*?

Comment: I've downvoted this because it's not a real question -- you're just asking for the entire code, ready to run. You haven't tried to do it yourself.  This is a 'help' forum, not a code mill.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict),  [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

data = """Python is a cool language but OCaml
is even cooler since it is purely functional"""

result = defaultdict(lambda: [0, []])
for i, l in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
    for k, v in Counter(l.split()).items():
        result[k][0] += v
        result[k][1].append(i+1)

for k, v in result.items():
    print('{1} {0} {2}'.format(k, *v))
```

Output:

```
1 since [2]
3 is [1, 2]
1 a [1]
1 it [2]
1 but [1]
1 purely [2]
1 cooler [2]
1 functional [2]
1 Python [1]
1 cool [1]
1 language [1]
1 even [2]
1 OCaml [1]
```

If the order matters, you can sort the result this way:

```
items = sorted(result.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1][0], t[0].lower()))
for k, v in items:
    print('{1} {0} {2}'.format(k, *v))
```

Output:

```
3 is [1, 2]
1 a [1]
1 but [1]
1 cool [1]
1 cooler [2]
1 even [2]
1 functional [2]
1 it [2]
1 language [1]
1 OCaml [1]
1 purely [2]
1 Python [1]
1 since [2]
```

Comment: How can I write this result to a csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Frequency tabulations are often best solved with a [counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter
word_count = Counter()
with open('input', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            word_count[word.strip().lower()] += 1

for word, count in word_count.iteritems():
    print "word: {}, count: {}".format(word, count)
```

Comment: `line.split()` operates on whitespace per default so the `" "` part is not needed. But you should perhaps wait to provide a full answer since the OP haven't shown any efforts what so ever. Nice answer though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you've already identified split to turn your string into a list of words. You want to list the lines on which each word occurs, however, so you should split the string first into lines, then into words. Then, you can create a dictionary, where keys are the words (put to lowercase first), and the values can be a structure containing the number of occurrences and the lines of occurrence.

You may also want to put in some code to check whether something is a valid word (e.g. whether it contains numbers), and to sanitise a word (remove punctuation). I'll leave these up to you.

```
def wsort(item):
    # sort descending by count, then ascending alphabetically
    word, freq = item
    return -freq['count'], word

def wfreq(str):
    words = {}

    # split by line, then by word
    lines = [line.split() for line in str.split('\n')]

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for word in lines[i]:
            # if the word is not in the dictionary, create the entry
            word = word.lower()
            if word not in words:
                words[word] = {'count':0, 'lines':set()}

            # update the count and add the line number to the set
            words[word]['count'] += 1
            words[word]['lines'].add(i+1)

    # convert from a dictionary to a sorted list using wsort to give the order
    return sorted(words.iteritems(), key=wsort)

inp = "Python is a cool language but OCaml\nis even cooler since it is purely functional"

for word, freq in wfreq(inp):
    # generate the desired list format
    lines = " ".join(str(l) for l in list(freq['lines']))
    print "%i %s %s" % (freq['count'], word, lines)
```

This should provide the exact same output as in your sample:

```
3 is 1 2
1 a 1
1 but 1
1 cool 1
1 cooler 2
1 even 2
1 functional 2
1 it 2
1 language 1
1 ocaml 1
1 purely 2
1 python 1
1 since 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all find all the words that are present in the text. Using `split()`.

In case the text is present in a file, then we will first get it into a string, and all it `text`. also remove all the `\n` from the text.

```
filin=open('file','r')
di = readlines(filin)

text = ''
for i in di:
     text += i</pre></code>
```

now check the number of times each word is there in the text. we will deal with the line numbers later.

```
dicts = {}
for i in words_list:
     dicts[i] = 0
for i in words_list:
    for j in range(len(text)):
        if text[j:j+len(i)] == i:
            dicts[i] += 1
```

now we have a dictionary with the words as keys and the values being the mumber of times the word appears in the text.

now for the line numbers:

```
dicts2 = {}
for i in words_list:
     dicts2[i] = 0
filin.seek(0)
for i in word_list:
    filin.seek(0)
    count = 1
    for j in filin:
        if i in j:
            dicts2[i] += (count,)
         count += 1
```

now dicts2 has the words as the key and the list of the line numbers it is in as the values. inside a tuple

if in case the data is already in a string, you just need to remove all the `\n`s.

`di = split(string_containing_text,'\n')`

and everything else will be the same.

i am sure you can format the output.

Comment: i am sorry about the bad formatting. i amnot on a pc. i hope you can understand. if not do leave a comment.

Comment: I fixed your formatting, now you must accept it...